Number of Sylow $7$- and $13$-subgroups in a group of order $11830$
This is part of a past qualifying exam problem.

Let $G$ be a group of order $11830 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13^2$. 
(1) How many Sylow $7$-subgroups does $G$ have? 
(2) How many Sylow $13$-subgroups does $G$ have?

Work so far. Let $n_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Using Sylow III, I can deduce the following: $n_7 \mid 2\cdot5\cdot13^2$ and $n_7 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ implies that $n_7 \in \{1,13^2\}$. Also, $n_{13} \mid 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ and $n_{13} \equiv 1 \mod 13$ implies that $n_{13} \in \{1,14\}$. However, I'm not sure where to go from here to determine the actual values.
In similar problems, I could rule out some possibilities by counting elements (e.g., I know if $n_7 = 169$ then $G$ must have $6\cdot 169$ elements of order $7$, etc.) and seeing if that number exceeds the size of the group, but so far that approach has not been successful here. At the moment I don't see how to apply anything else that I know to solve this problem, so I must be missing something.
I'm guessing even a small hint would allow me to continue and solve the problem.
n.b. I should mention that since this is a past qualifying exam problem I should be able to do it without the use of a calculator or computer.

Here's the full problem from the exam (with all parts) for additional context:

Let $G$ be a group of order $11830 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13^2$. In this problem, you will show that $G$ is not simple.
(1) How many Sylow $7$-subgroups does $G$ have?
(2) How many Sylow $13$-subgroups does $G$ have?
(3) Show that $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $14$.
(4) Show that, if $G$ is simple, then $G$ admits a nontrivial homomorphism to $S_{14}$.
(5) Show that $G$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{14}$.
(6) Show that $G$ is not simple.


As you have worked out, the possible answers for (1) are 1 and 169. I think that is the expected answer for (1). Of course, there could just be one if $G$ is cyclic. Suppose you are meant to conclude there is only one no matter what $G$ is. Then question (4) makes no sense. So I conclude "1 or 169" is the expected answer to (1).

@2'59'2 That's what I was thinking, but I also thought maybe I was missing something obvious. But then, similarly, "1 or 14" for (2)?

I think that from the start you can assume that $G$ is simple. Then the flow of questions makes sense arriving at a contradiction in $(6)$. I agree, the formulation is sloppy.

We can actually prove that $n_{13}=1$.
We need the following three lemmas that are not difficult to prove or you might've seen them:
Lemma 1. Every group of order $5\times 13^2$ is abelian.
Lemma 2. For each odd number $m>1$, every group of order $2m$ has a subgroup of order $m$.
Lemma 3. Each group of order $7\times 13^2$ with normal Sylow $7$-subgroup is abelian.
Proof. On the contrary, assume that $n_{13}=14$, and so $|G:N_G(P_{13})|=14$. This means $N_G(P_{13})$ contains a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$, say $P_5$.
By Lemma 1, we get that $N_G(P_{13})=P_{13}\times P_5$, and so $P_{13}\le C_G(P_5)\le N_G(P_5)$, which means $13\nmid |G:N_G(P_5)|=n_5$. Now since $n_5\in \{1,2,7,14\}$, and we get that $n_5=1$.
Using Normalizer-Centralizer, we get that $G/C_G(P_5)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(P_5)\cong C_4$, and so $|G:C_G(P_5)|\in \{1,2\}$.
Note that $C_G(P_5)=P_5\times M$, where $M\le C_G(P_5)$ and $|M|\in \{7\times 13^2,2\times 7\times 13^2\}$. Either case using Lemma 2, there exists $L\le C_G(P_5)$ of order $7\times 13^2$.
Now we prove that $P_7\in Syl_7(L)\subseteq Syl_7(G)$ is normal in $L$. If not, then $n_7=169$, and so we get that, $$|L| - \text{number of elements of order } 7=|L| - 6\times 169 =169,$$ which implies that $P_{13}\triangleleft L$, and so $P_7\le N_L(P_{13})\le N_G(P_{13})$, which is a contradiction, and $P_7\triangleleft  L$. Now by Lemma 3, we get that $L=P_7\times P_{13}$, and so $P_7\le C_G(P_{13})\le N_G(P_{13})$, which is a contradiction, and $P_{13}=1$.

Some additional note:
(1) Using our proof, we can show that $n_5=1$, too. Hence if $G$ is a group of order $11830$, then $G\cong (P_{13} \times C_5) \rtimes K$, where $K$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_7$ or $D_{14}$ (the dihedral group of order $14$).
(2) Since $|Aut(C_{13}\times C_{13})|=168\times 156$ is divisible by $7$, there exists a group of order $7\times 13^2$ with a non-normal Sylow $7$-subgroup, and so there exists a group of order $11830=2\times 5 \times 7 \times 13^2$, with a non-normal Sylow $7$-subgroup, which means the correct answer to parts (1) and (2) of the problem is $n_7\in \{1,169\}$ and $n_{13}=1$.
(3) Using Lemma 2, we could actually get the result way easier. This lemma assures us of having a (normal) subgroup of order $5\times 7\times 13^2$, say $N$. Now using Sylow theorems, $P_{13}\triangleleft N$, where $P_{13} \in Syl_{13}(N)\subseteq Syl_{13}(G)$. Note that $P_{13}$ is also characteristic in $N$, and so $P_{13}$ is normal in $G$.
